# How do I prevent JsonWriter from adding too many newlines while serializing a multidimensional array?

Tags: c#, arrays, json, serialization, json.net

Recently I have been working on a tilemap editor. I am using C#, MonoGame, and Newtonsoft.Json
Basically I want to serialize a Map class with a list of Layer classes.
The problem is, when serializing `int[,] MAP` inside of the Layer class, it is adding newlines for each element of the array.

I want to achieve this output:

```
"MAP": 
  [
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17],
    [17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17,17]
  ]
```

What I get instead:

```
"MAP": 
  [
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17
  ],
  [
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    17
  ],
  and so on
```

How can I avoid this?

My serialization code:

```
public void Save(string path, object obj)
{
   using (TextWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
   using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
   {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();

        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
        writer.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) to toggle the writer's `Formatting` setting to `None` at the appropriate intervals:

```
public class CustomFormattingMatrixConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(int[,]);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        int[,] array = (int[,])value;
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        for (int i = 0, bound0 = array.GetUpperBound(0); i <= bound0; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
            for (int j = 0, bound1 = array.GetUpperBound(1); j <= bound1; j++)
            {
                writer.WriteValue(array[i, j]);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        }
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it with your serializer like this:

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Converters.Add(new CustomFormattingMatrixConverter());

writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
```

Working demo here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/q3P0en

Comment: No problem; glad I could help.

Answer (score -1):

```
writer.Formatting = Formatting.None;
```

instead of

```
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
```

Comment: Yeah, well Formatting.None puts everything into a single line of Json data